# Phonegap and SoundCloud API

Tags: api, cordova, authentication, upload, soundcloud

i'm trying using `soundcloud API` in `Phonegap` app, but i'm wondering which is the best practice for letting users signup/login via SoundCloud API and upload music to SoundCloud?

I can't find anything about Phonegap and soundcloud , can you please tell me some best practice and/or resource to follow? Or if it's out there any phonegap plugin for example for soundcloud

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This phonegap plugin can be used for the auth process:

https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap

Comment: really really good resource man, do you know if it has soundcloud oauth too? on oauth.io it's listed as i can see...

Comment: yes, they have ouath - and they are in the list of auth.io, here are the docs: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#token

Comment: absolutely helpfull man i was searching for such plugin from lont time ago damn :P thank you

Comment: Does it also let me access the tracks uploaded to user's SoundCloud?